# Codeigniter: Remove controller from URL and disable access through the original path

Tags: codeigniter

Original URL

```
mydomain.com/main/portfolio
```

Now I need to remove the controller name from the URL with the below Route which i have done successfully:

```
//Controller Name: main
$route['(:any)'] = "main/$1";
```

My new URL is good:

```
mydomain.com/portfolio
```

But the original URL is still accessible which I don't want for SEO purposes:

```
mydomain.com/main/portfolio
```

How can I have my good URL run as normal and block the old URL.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use `.htaccess` for this

Answer (score 1):

You can create a not found page and redirect unwanted routes to that.
For instance you can create error controller:

```
class Error extends CI_Controller {     
    public function error_404() {
        // send 404 header
        $this->output->set_status_header('404');
        // load a custom not found page view template
        $this->load->view('error_404');
    }        
}
```

Then in the routes.php you can catch those URLs which contains the "main/" like this:

```
// this should be placed above the (:any) route
$route['main/(:any)'] = 'error/error_404';
$route['(:any)'] = "main/$1";
```

Comment: Is that ok for SEO?

Answer (score 0):

```
RedirectMatch "^/main/(.*)" "http://www.example.com/$1"
```

More examples available [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html).